# Jenkins pipeline build triggers is missing save/apply buttons?

Tags: jenkins

When visiting job//job/master/configure in order to set the
"github hook trigger for GITscm polling checkbox" there is no way to insure this setting is actually being saved? should there be a save or apply button.

I am unsure and I am new to jenkins

Comment: There should be Save/Apply buttons at the bottom. They are missing from my view as well; I'm on v2.204.2.

Comment: @MaxCascone did you manage to solve the issue? I got the same problem (I'm on the same version)

Answer (score 0):

I think so - what I realized is that when you use Get script from SCM - that is, you’re using a `Jenkinsfile`, all of the configuration is set in the jenkinsfile. So changing config in the UI would conflict with the JF and also be inconsistent with its own setting.

At least, I *think* that’s the explanation.